# Using Apache mod_status with Prestashop 1.6 (Error 404)

Tags: apache, server, prestashop, status, netdata

I am trying to setup mod_status to work with Prestashop 1.6. Prestashop does not know this URL so it is redirecting to home page. It can be probably fixed in .htaccess but nothing works so far, for example this condition has absolutely no effect: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found a solution and it seems to be working correctly.

Try adding simple alias to apache2.conf:

```
Alias /server-status /var/www/html
```

...and restart server. Then server status will be available at www.your-domain.com/server-status.

Source: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2006-03-05/htaccess-vs-apache-server-status